# How to import a file, residing in the same app, as blob using XMLHttpRequest in ReactJS

Tags: ajax, reactjs, file, import, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to import a file in my ReactJS app using XMLHttpRequest. The file is in the same app, however the response is always undefined. The response type of the request is 'blob'. This is the relevant code:

```
var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
targetUrl = require('./test.xlsx');
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();    
oReq.open('get',proxyUrl + targetUrl, true);
oReq.responseType = 'blob';
oReq.onload = function () {
    var blob = oReq.response;       
};
oReq.send();
```

The proxyUrl is to avoid the CORS error since it's an ajax request. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `oReq.onreadystatechage` than `oReq.onload`?

Comment: Are you using Create React App? You could put your file in the `public` directory, and just fetch from the root: `fetch('/test.xlsx')`

Comment: @sthotakura using onreadystatechange also doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - need to import the file and use that in the XMLHttpRequest

```
import file from './test.xlsx';

componentDidMount() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    oReq.open('get', file , true);
    oReq.responseType = 'blob';
    oReq.onload = function () {
        var blob = oReq.response;       
    };
    oReq.send();
}
```